# Identify curly bracket and multiple instances in list using TCL

Tags: regex, tcl

I'm reading a large file and I'm only interested in small part of the file as shown below.

```
TC.0.Type = Bob 1
TC.1.Type = Mark 1
TC.2.Type =
TC.3.Type =
TC.4.Type = Fred 1
TC.5.Type =
TC.6.Type =
TC.7.Type = 
TC.8.Type =
TC.9.Type = Fred 1
```

I've created a variable that is now holds this information

```
data = "{Bob 1} {Mark 1} {} {} {Fred 1} {} {} {} {} {Fred 1}"
```

TC is always between 0-9, so length is known.

What I would like to do is:

1) If there are multiple instances of "Fred 1" and delete it.
2) Find the first empty slot and determine the index.

Question 1) 
Is it typical to get brackets when using lappend? I expected this to be only in the case of empty fields

```
set data ""
for {set j 0} {$j < 10} {incr j} {  
    lappend data $fromfile
    }
puts "Data in list = $data"
```

Question 2) I've even tried using regexp to pick out empty but don't seem to be successful.

Find empty field {}

```
set j 0
for {set i 0} {$i < $ldata} {incr i} {
# set nline [split $data "\s"]
# puts "data ($i) = $nline"
if {[regexp {\{.*\}} $data]} {
   puts " Found {}"
   incr j
   puts "j = $j"
}
}
```

Find field with name e.g. Bob 1

```
for {set i 0} {$i < $ldata} {incr i} {
if {[regexp {\{.*[a-zA-Z0-9]\}} $data]} {
   puts " Found something with names"
}
}
```

Would appreciate if someone can advice and guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lsearch` command is going to be tremendously useful for what you are doing, *especially* with the `-all` option.

```
set data "{Bob 1} {Mark 1} {} {} {Fred 1} {} {} {} {} {Fred 1}"
puts [lsearch -all -exact $data "Fred 1"]
# ==> 4 9
```

We can also use it to remove specific values:

```
puts [lsearch -all -inline -exact -not $data "Fred 1"]
# ==> {Bob 1} {Mark 1} {} {} {} {} {} {}
```

To find the first empty slot, we just do:

```
puts [lsearch -exact $data ""]
# ==> 2
```

We most definitely would expect braces back from list operations; that's how empty list elements are expressed.

Comment: Hi Donal, thank you. I think I was making it over complicated. However for my learning, could correct my regexp for identifying empty slot and one with the string. I would very much appreciate it. Thank you